# Export files from photoshop to android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, photoshop

I am using photoshop to create a graphic that I want to span the entire width of the screen on any device type. However the below affect is what I am getting. I exported the original file as 320x480 Then scaled the image by 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, and 4.0. How do I achieve a graphic that scales well and spans the entire width of the screen?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ImageView#ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType)

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
> both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
> larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).
> The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax:
> android:scaleType="centerCrop".

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/create_account"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to minimalize cropping?

Comment: Try 
`android:scaleX="0.8"
android:scaleY="0.8"`